# How to reference currect element inside its defaultChecked - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I have a dynamic array
a[1,3]
I have 3 checkboxes which have name and value and I want to default check them based on the dynamic array a. I want to **pass** inside defaultCheck each current child's value (by reference and not manually by the actual number(1,2,3)).Is that possible?

Something like defaultChecked={giveCheck(self.value} and be executed in the beginning so the checkboxes get their default check status

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="1" defaultChecked={giveCheck(self.value}/>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="2" defaultChecked={giveCheck(self.value}/>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="3" defaultChecked={giveCheck(self.value}/>


giveCheck(value) {
if(a.indexOf(value)>=0){
return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want these checkboxes to be uncontrolled instead of controlled components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Old answer

Yes, that's definitely possible. In my example below I store the array in the state and for each of your inputs you check in that value exists in the array. You can use `indexOf()` if you want, but I prefer `includes()` as it is supported on all major browsers.

Also, you might want to change your `name` attributes to be unique.

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      a: [1,3]
    };
  }
 
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="1" defaultChecked={this.state.a.includes(1)} />
        <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="2" defaultChecked={this.state.a.includes(2)} />
        <input type="checkbox" name="c" value="3" defaultChecked={this.state.a.includes(3)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

If you have more than 3 elements (say 50) and code readability is a concern, you can generate the inputs in a loop:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      a: [1,3]
    };
  }
 
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {[...Array(50)].map(
          (v, i) => {
            return <input type="checkbox" name={"a"+i} value={i+1} defaultChecked={this.state.a.includes(i+1)} />
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

#### New answer

The short answer is: no, you cannot read the property of value before the component has been rendered. Basically what you are asking is for the code to read what you wrote earlier in the code. Unlike an event that triggers at runtime, this would have to happen on execution.

You could obviously just write the number twice:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="3" defaultChecked={giveCheck(3)}/>
```

but if you don't want this, create a function that returns an input element. This also eliminates the need for a "checker" function - just do it all in one function. This way, you input the value once, but can return code that uses that parameter in both places:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      a: [1,3]
    };
  }
  
  renderInput(value) {
    return <input type="checkbox" name="a" value={value} defaultChecked={this.state.a.includes(value)} /> 
  }
 
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.renderInput(1)}
        {this.renderInput(2)}
        {this.renderInput(3)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I have multiple arrays a[1,3] b[2,4,5] etc so name can't be unique (actually the set of inputs with same name will add their value in the a certain array.

In your code you add the value of checkbox in function manually by number (1,2,3)
and one approach is to create dynamically the checkboxes. 
But is it possible to add the value as a reference of element's attribute?
For example with onClick you can check event.target.value and get the value but that doesn't work in defaultChecked (at least the way I have tried)

Comment: @iMMuNiTy, I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: by mistake i pressed enter before completing the comment please see again. I want to add a reference not actual number in the function

Comment: @iMMuNiTy, could you update your question and add how you would *like* the code to work. It doesn't have to run, just to explain it better. Do that and I'll take a look

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. I have changed a bit the question. (i want to pass the value by reference not by number). input elements already exist (haven't been created dynamically) so i want to just copy paste the same code inside each input tag

Comment: is it possible without rendering the inputs (i have got 50 inputs tags from pug view convertion.
I want to just replace (ctrl+H) for  type="checkbox" replace it with type="checkbox" defaultChecked={giveCheck(value)}

Every input has value as an attribute

So i dont want to write 50 times the giveCheck(1,2....) etc

Comment: @iMMuNiTy, sadly, no.

Comment: Please include also that statement ( that its not Possible) keep also the rest of the answers so I can mark as answered

Comment: @iMMuNiTy, Already state that in the beginning of the "new answer" part. The other answers are also there, just collapsed :)